# How do I make me bypass permission restrictions

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I have a command and I want to make one of my commands to bypass the locked permissions..

How do I make the code bypass the permission restrictions with my id?

Code:

```
    if (!message.guild.me.hasPermission('BAN_MEMBERS')) return message.reply('I don\'t have permission to ban members!', { allowedMentions: { repliedUser: false } });
    if (!message.member.hasPermission('BAN_MEMBERS')) return message.reply('You don\'t have permission to ban members!', { allowedMentions: { repliedUser: false } });
    if (!args[0]) return message.reply('Provide someone to ban!', { allowedMentions: { repliedUser: false } });
    let check = false;
    const target = message.mentions.members.first() || await message.guild.members.fetch(args[0]).catch(e => {
        check = true;
        return message.reply('Can\'t find specefied member! Provide a valid id', { allowedMentions: { repliedUser: false } });
    });
    if (check) return;
    if(target.id === message.author.id) return message.reply('Why would you want to ban yourself?!', { allowedMentions: { repliedUser: false } });
    if(target.id === client.user.id) return message.reply('Why would you want to ban me?!', { allowedMentions: { repliedUser: false } });
    let reason = "No reason provided.";
    if (args[1]) reason = args.splice(1).join(" ");
    if (!target.bannable) return message.reply('Can\'t ban specified member! Make sure I\'m above them in the heirarchy', { allowedMentions: { repliedUser: false } });

            await target.ban({ reason: reason });
            const banEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
                 .setColor("#ff0000")
                                 .setFooter(message.guild.name, message.guild.iconURL())
                                 .addField("**Moderation**", "Ban")
                                 .addField("**Name**", `${target.user.tag}`)
                                 .addField("**Banned By**", message.author.username)
                                 .addField("**Reason**", `${reason || "**No Reason**"}`)
                                 .addField("**Date**", message.createdAt.toLocaleString())
                                 .setTimestamp();
            message.channel.send(banEmbed)
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second line, the one that checks for the user's permissions is what you must update. Inside of the condition, also make sure that the user's id is not yours.
Something like this

```
if(!message.member.hasPermission('BAN_MEMBERS') && message.author.id != "09128029381") return message.reply("no");
```